# pass a variable with quotes to the snippet renderer in the shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

I want to pass a variable with quotes to the snippet renderer. Here is the renderer:

```
{%- render 'image', img: image, width: '100' -%}
```

And I need to pass the width by replacing **'100'** with a value from a variable that looks like this:

```
{% assign image_width = block.settings.width %}
```

I do this:

```
{%- render 'image', img: image, width: image_width -%}
```

But it doesn't work because the value is numeric without quotes. I also tried passing this value through `{% capture %}`, like this:

```
{% capture image_width %}'{{ block.settings.width }}'{% endcapture %}
{%- render 'image', img: image, width: image_width -%}
```

Note that I have wrapped the value inside `{% capture %}` in quotes - `'{{ block.settings.width }}'`. But it doesn't work either.

Please tell me how I can pass the value in quotes as text in the snippet renderer.

Thank you!

Comment: @DavidThomas, Hello. Sorry, I didn't see your reply. yes now I saw it in the remote question. i looked at your jsfiddle, and your code unfortunately doesn't answer my question. i need two columns via `grid-template-areas`, but @ Paulie_D already told me that i can't use grid. so, i'm asking for html access from the client. thanks for your help! i really appreciate it!

Comment: @DavidThomas, Thank you so much again! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. Just need to add empty quotes using method `append`. Like this:

```
| append: ''
```

The result is the following code:

```
{% assign image_width = block.settings.width | append: '' %}
{%- render 'image', img: image, width: image_width -%}
```